# In Foundry Slate, how do I dynamically index into an array or object using handlebars?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

In Foundry's Slate application, I'd like to index into an array or other object based upon some seletion in another widget -- say, choosing a column from a dropdown.

How can I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lookup handlebars helper [reference](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/helpers.html#helpers).

The lookup helper looks like the following {{lookup arrayName index}} and is equivalent to arrayName[index] in javascript.

This also works for objects as `{{lookup objectName key}}`.

And you can do it for nested things as well:

`{{lookup a "b" "c"}}`

where the context is `{ a: { b: { c: "test" } } }`

Will return `"test"`

To simplify things, you can also write a small helper function that takes in the selection and the data, does any necessary work to produce the correct output and then returns that output to display elsewhere.